# How to prevent repetition in Angular html?

Tags: html, angular

I have an input in my html as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="({required: <some_condition>, invalid: <some_condition>}) as emailErrors">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" validate-onblur [class.is-invalid]="emailErrors.required || emailErrors.invalid" [attr.aria-invalid]="emailErrors.required || emailErrors.invalid" [attr.aria-describedby]="emailErrors.required || emailErrors.invalid ? 'email-error' : undefined">
    <div *ngIf="emailErrors.required" id="email-error">
        <p class="error-msg">{{messages.EMAIL_REQ}}</p>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Here in my `<input>` tag I'm repeting this condition 3 times: `emailErrors.required || emailErrors.invalid`.

Can I store this condition here in a variable, so that I do not have to repeat it?

P.S. I'm new in Angular

Comment: As answerd by @Yong Shaun You can use getter approach.  Even angular material heavily using getter approach. You can check material code here:https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#errorstate

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the [template form](https://angular.io/guide/forms#build-a-template-driven-form) of Angular. These are fairly simpler to implement.

In the code below make sure you give `name` property on the `input` field otherwise an error will be thrown, while working on with `[(ngModel)]`

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="mail" required [(ngModel)]="model.email" #mail="ngModel">
  <span *ngIf="mail.invalid">
        {{messages.EMAIL_REQ}}
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: How will this approach add `aria-invalid` and `aria-describedby` in the input tag?

Comment: @KeshavBhatiya Try the same approach `[attr.aria-invalid]="mail.invalid"`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not introduce an additional property in the wrapping `<ng-container>`? And seeing that `emailErrors.invalid` isn't used anywhere else, it could be removed if it's unneeded.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="({required: <condition_1>, reqOrInv: <condition_1> || <condition_2>}) as emailErrors">
  <input 
    type="email" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Email" 
    validate-onblur 
    [class.is-invalid]="emailErrors.reqOrInv" 
    [attr.aria-invalid]="emailErrors.reqOrInv" 
    [attr.aria-describedby]="emailErrors.reqOrInv ? 'email-error' : undefined"
  >
  <div *ngIf="emailErrors.required" id="email-error">
    <p class="error-msg">{{messages.EMAIL_REQ}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

But as @YashwardhanPauranik noted in their answer, you're better off using Angular [template driven or reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview). They provide more granular control.